# OpenGL x-axis in inverted for some reason

Tags: opengl, rotation, coordinate-systems

My camera is acting as if the x-axis is inverted when i try to simply rotate the camera around the xz plane to view my model at the origin.

```
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)800 / (float)600, 0.1f, 1000.f);
viewMatrix  = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(2.0f*sin(30.0f*(PI/180.0f)), 0, 2.0f*cos(30.0f*(PI/180.0f))),
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
);
modelMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.5f));
```

As you can see the camera position starts at 0 degrees, (x=0, z=2), and as the degrees approach 30 the camera should be rotating right to the 30 degree mark. Instead, since the x-axis is acting like its inverted for some reason, my camera is rotating left instead of right and viewing the model at 330 degrees.

Comment: It is totally unclear how these matrices will be applied, so basically anything can happen.

Comment: The GLM library is pretty standard in most OpenGL applications i dont think its random :S

Comment: I know the glm. But I don;t know what you do to this matrices afterwards. It is very easy to screw things up, I.e. use the wrong multiplication order at some point.

Comment: The above code is the only change i make to the matrices before being sent to the shader. GLM is quite popular so i assume it uses the correct order

Answer (score 0):

At 30 degrees, x=1 and z=1.73, which makes it look like the camera is going left. X should be negated.

Comment: Sorry but why would the camera go left with a positive x-value in OpenGL's RHS http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/courses/cs371/f10/G3D/manual/coords.png